# SQL and Java Date Comparison

Tags: java, sql

I am re-writing my doubt. I have a java.sql.Timestamp value something like "2014-02-12 17:40:16.0". And I want to compare this with a column in DB which is of type "TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE" and values in that column will be format like "12-FEB-14 05.40.41.385416000 PM". When I compare it with exact time stamp value from java program I am not getting output. But If I give a time difference which is greater than five and half hour then I will get output.

Thanks!!

Comment: can you post samples of your query as well as code for us to identify?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Are you sure your Date object contains the timestamp as well?

Comment: I think a snippet of the query could be helpful. Meanwhile, please refer to this sql data types and their format:
DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD,  
DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,  
TIMESTAMP - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,   as you can see sql's DATE type doesn't hold hours and minutes, you might wanna change to DATETIME

Comment: Where does `str` come from? What Java class is that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your `str` variable is in format of something like `2013-03-11 12:23:34.0`

Then you can construct your timestamp using `str` directly:

```
stmt.setTimestamp(1, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype for column in you table shouldn't be date but datetime. Then the comparison will be something like :

```
java.util.Date date = yourquery();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(((Date) str).getTime());
statement = connection.statement("select * from table where datecolumn >= ?");
statement.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry Now My doubt is now whatever column we are having in DB is of "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE ". So when I compare date from Java  to that column I am getting five and half hour difference. And on emore point I observerd is that data stored in 12 hour format in DB with "AM/PM". But in Java we are getting in 24 hour format

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setDate` method from `PreparedStatement`. No need to create Timestamp object.

```
connection.statement("select * from table where datecolumn >= ?");
statement.setDate(1, dateObject);
```